# open gcc on centos

Tags: c++, c, linux

Want to ask after I installed gcc on linux, where can I found and open it. I need that to compile c/c++ code.
FYI, I'm using centos 5.5 and gcc installed with yum install gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake
command and successfull.

Thank you

Comment: Please rephrase this question more clearly to prevent it being closed

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` is a command line program, not an graphical environment to write, compile, run programs. You write your files with some text editor, like `gedit` or `vim` or `emacs` or... There are also IDEs (Integrated Development Environments) on Unix/Linux, but I personally like to write my stuff in `xemacs`, so I won't comment on them.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal/console and change to the directory (with `cd path/to/directory`) with the source code you want to compile.
With the command `gcc sourcefile1.c sourcefile2.c -o output` you compile your own simple programs.

When you've downloaded a complexer program there is normally a configure file and a make file. First execute `./configure` which will check if your system satisfies all dependencies for the program and then execute `make` which build (compiles) everything. 
Most programs support `sudo make install` too, which will install the program on the whole system (normally in /usr/bin/).

Comment: I strongly suggest to a newbie to pass `-Wall -g` to `gcc` and to learn how to use the `gdb` debugger